# Why did Merlin not heal his fatigue with magic?

Tags: tv, magic, merlin-bbc

In Merlin Season 1 Epi 1, Merlin is appointed Prince Arthur's servant by King Uther Pendragon, after saving Arthur's life from the witch's dagger.

Then Merlin becomes fatigued and bruised from being Arthur's sparring aide.

When Merlin returned to his quarters, Gaius the royal physician had to heal/soothe Merlin's fatigue and bruises.

Give me good excuse/reason why Merlin had not used magic to heal himself. I mean, he used magic to polish swords, clean boots, repair armour, etc for Arthur within the confines of his quarters he shared with Gaius. Why did he not use magic to heal himself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a couple reasons:

- Merlin has not yet learned any of the [healing spells](http://merlin.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_spells) in that episode.
- Healing magic is difficult, and Merlin is not particularly skilled in that area.

  - I believe it was hinted at in a couple episodes that he has to envision all the pieces of the anatomy that he has to repair - blood vessels, muscles, and so on.
- "Fatigue" cannot be healed, as the magic would tire him out.

Comment: The miraculous healing would also have been hard to explain. He had to hide his magic and Arthur would have wondered how an untrained servant would be just fine the very next day after recieving such a beating. Not showing any of the fatigue or pain he should have. That aside, I don't recall Merlin healing himself even in later seasons, when he was more experienced and powerful. He always treated his wounds normaly or was healed by someone else, if I remember correctly. Maybe it is very hard or even impossible for him to properly heal himself.

Comment: @Sebastian_H I -think-, but am not certain, that he did heal himself near the end of Season 5.  I have a vague memory of him laying wounded in the forest, using magic, and then passing out.

Comment: I believe you refer to S5E08 - The Hollow Queen. Spoilers! Merlin is poisoned by Morgana after being tricked. He tries to use magic but it fails. It’s not clear if he tries to heal himself but it’s likely. However, after the poison is neutralized by an antidote made of herbs, he can use magic again. But even then he does not heal his minor leg wound which slows him down. In S5E10 – The Kindness of Strangers he is hit by a crossbow bolt. Again he is not healing himself but is later healed by the Dragon after calling him. So healing himself does seems impossible for him, for some reason.

Comment: "Fatigue cannot be healed as the magic would wear him out" Merlin would have to tap into perpetual energy for this :D +1 for that line